# How do I display a CheckboxListTile text in a single line, using ListView builder?

Tags: flutter, listview, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am trying to display the text of checkbox in a single line, but it splits into a second line. Here is the code:

I created a custom ExpansionListTile:

```
customExpansionTile(
    context,
    "Visting Time",
    true,
    Icon(Icons.timer_rounded, color: HexColor("#5344ed")), //leading
    <Widget>[
        Container(
            child: Row(
                children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
                            child: ListTile(  
                                //font change
                                subtitle: ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount: checkBoxListTileModelForVisting.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                        return new Container(
                                            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                            child: Column(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                    new CheckboxListTile(
                                                        controlAffinity:
                                                        ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                                                        activeColor: HexColor("#5344ed"),
                                                        dense: true,
                                                        //font change
                                                        title: new Text(
                                                            checkBoxListTileModelForVisting[index].title,
                                                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                                            fontSize: 12,
                                                        ),
                                                    ),
                                                    value: checkBoxListTileModelForVisting[index]
                                                    .isCheck,
                                                    secondary: Container(
                                                        padding:EdgeInsets.only(left: 100),
                                                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.9,
                                                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *0.2,
                                                        child:
                                                        checkBoxListTileModelForVisting[index].isCheck ==true?
                                                        IconButton(
                                                            tooltip:"Pick Time",
                                                            onPressed: () {
                                                                _VisitingTimeDialogue(
                                                                    checkBoxListTileModelForVisting[index]
                                                                .title);
                                                            },
                                                            icon: Icon(Icons.add)
                                                        )
                                                    : null),
                                                    onChanged: (bool? val) {
                                                        itemChangeforVisiting(val!, index);
                                                    }),
```

Wednesday is not displaying properly, please tell me where I'm doing something wrong.

[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `width` with `height`

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.9, 
                                        
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *0.2,
```

like

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *0.9, 
                                        
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.2,
```

i think your `secondary` takes up extra space, it makes sense to use expanded instead of width

and add to `Text` `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` and `maxLines: 1`

like

```
Text('your text', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, maxLines: 1)
```

if it doesn't help you try to use autoSizeText packages

Answer (score 0):

**checkboxlisttile wrap to container and give max width**